# Assigning a SAS statement to a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset that contains the names and attributes of variables that I want to define for a dataset within a macro.  For example:

```
variable_name = "filedate"  
variable_length = 8  
variable_label = "Date file was loaded"  
variable_format = "date9."
variable_derivation = "filedate = today()"
```

The macro does something like this:

```
%macro create_ds;  

    data _null_;
    set variable_definitions;
        call symputx('varname', variable_name);
        call symputx('varlength', variable_length);
        call symputx('varlabel', variable_label);
        call symputx('varformat', variable_format);
        call symputx('varderive', variable_definition);
    run;  

    data newds;
        attrib &varname length=&varlength label="&varlabel" format=&varformat;
        &varderive;
    run;

%mend create_ds;
```

What I hoped the datastep would look like is:

```
data newds;
    attrib filedate length=8 label="Date file was loaded" format=date9.;
    filedate = today();
run;
```

What I actually get is:

```
data newds;
    attrib filedate length=8 label="Date file was loaded" format=date9.;
    .;
run;
```

It then throws an error because "." is not a valid statement.

Is there a way to assign a datastep statement to a macro variable and actually have it execute?

Comment: Typo error, variable_derivation = "filedate = today()" but then call symputx('varderive', variable_definition);  derivation vs definition.

Comment: Yep.  You have a . because it's assigning missing to that - otherwise it would work just fine.

Comment: @Reese and Joe, since you two effectively answered the question, I recommend you post an answer. :)